# Uploading a document and sending within XForm

Tags: upload, content-management-system, document, episerver

I'm using **EPiServer CMS 7.5** MVC application.

I can only see textboxes and buttons while creating a new form. I would like to have a link, which uploads a document, when clicked. Then this document should be able to view while looking to form data and also this should be attached along with the mail.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

There is no file upload control in XForm editor. One option - modify how XForm is rendered. XForm in EPiServer uses display templates to render. One way how to add file upload is to create your own XForm display template and add file upload. Display template will be used for all XForms in your application.

To create display template, create XForm.cshtml under /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ in Visual Studio. Here is sample of source code of XForm.cshtml:

```
@using EPiServer.HtmlParsing
@using EPiServer.Web.Mvc.Html
@model EPiServer.XForms.XForm

@if (ViewData["XFormActionResult"] is EPiServer.Web.Mvc.XForms.XFormSuccessActionResult)
{
    <strong>Form posted.</strong>
}
else
{
    using (Html.BeginXForm(Model, new { @class = "form xform" }))
    {
        if (Model != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlFragment fragment in (IEnumerable<HtmlFragment>)ViewData["XFormFragments"] ?? Model.CreateHtmlFragments())
            {
                // here can override particular fragment
                // for example, check if TextBox Css class is "file-upload"
                // then replace it with file upload
                @Html.Fragment(fragment)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that you have to handle posting the form yourself. This article describes well how to do it: http://www.eyecatch.no/blog/2013/01/using-xforms-and-mvc-in-an-episerver-7-block/

Then on OnActionExecuting in BasePageController you can handle file uploading. You can store it in the blob (in EPi 7 VPP) and store reference (GUID) in the XForm.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please help me in file uploading as I'm completely new to episerver. How can I get the document on OnActionExecuting in BasePageController and pass the store reference along with the form data

Comment: Be aware, the file name must be XForm.cshtml and not XForms.cshtml.